# How to go to a line if a wrong value is inputted

Tags: java, loops

I've been trying to figure out this: how to ensure that the program continues to run until the right value is entered and not terminate if a wrong value is entered.

Code:

```
package class3;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class dayName {

public static void main(String args[]){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nEnter any of the following values from 0 to 7 and \nI'll tell you the corresponding day.\n");
    int day = input.nextInt();

    switch (day){

    case 0: day = 0;
    if (day == 0)
        System.out.println("\nThat would be Sunday!\n");
        break;
    case 1: day = 1;
    if (day == 1)
        System.out.println("\nThat would be Monday!\n");
        break;
    case 2: day = 2;
    if (day == 2)
        System.out.println("\nThat would be Tuesday!\n");
        break;
    case 3: day = 3;
    if (day == 3)
        System.out.println("\nThat would be Wednesday!\n");
        break;
    case 4: day = 4;
    if (day == 4)
        System.out.println("\nThat would be Thursday!\n");
        break;
    case 5: day = 5;
    if (day == 5)
        System.out.println("\nThat would be Friday!\n");
        break;
    case 6: day = 6;
    if (day == 6)
        System.out.println("\nThat would be Saturday!\n");
        break;
    default: if(day < 0 && day > 6);
        System.out.println("\nThere's no day as such!\n");
        System.exit(0);

    }
}

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use an infinite loop with an exit condition.

Comment: `if(day < 0 && day > 6);` change to `if(day < 0 || day > 6)` OR remove it at all.

Comment: change your `default :` to `default : System.out.println("\nThere's no day as such!\n");`

Comment: Please explain why you switch-case on a number, then change the value to the same value, then recheck the value to what you just set...?

Comment: "if (something) **;** " is a [noop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP), `a=2;if(a==2)` makes no sense, and you should always use braces `if(something){ somethingElse; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean isValid = false;
do
{
    final int day = scanner.nextInt();
    if (day >= 0 && day <= 6)
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
         switch (day)
         {
            case 0:
              System.out.println("Sunday");
              break;
            case 1:
              System.out.println("Monday");
              break;
            case 2:
              System.out.println("Tuesday");
              break;
            case 3:
              System.out.println("Wednesday");
              break;
            case 4:
              System.out.println("Thursday");
              break;
            case 5:
              System.out.println("Friday");
              break;
            case 6:
              System.out.println("Saturday");
              break;
            default:
              System.out.println("Incorrect");
        }
    }
} while (!isValid);
```

This code works for me. You must have done something wrong if its not working for you.

Comment: Tried both cases, reporting error on curly brace: Syntax  error, insert "while (Expression) ; to complete do statement. And the while Expression is there already

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the latest code?

Comment: The switch should go into the else branch of the if.

Comment: Yep. That would be a good thing to do. Edited my answer to include it that way.